# How do I disable the Funambol updater in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, funambol

Is it possible to delete the Funambol update checker in Outlook for Windows XP? How?

I'm using Funambol 8.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no way in the client's UI to disable the sw-update.
A possible hack: you can change the value of this win registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Funambol\OutlookClient\updater\url-check

Just set its value to 0, the client will log an error (in the log file) saying the url is invalid, and will not proceed with the sw-update. On the UI, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading this: You need to create the key on a per user account basis, apparently.